# Как получить доступ к сайту написанному на фреймворке Rocket.rs и расположенному по адресу localhost с другого компьютера подключенного к той же сети?

Tags: веб-программирование, сеть, rust

Я могу зайти на свой сайт по адресу http://localhost:8000/ и он прекрасно работает.
В данный момент конфигурация сервера выглядит вот так:

```
Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.63s
     Running `target/debug/weather_rocket_app`
 Configured for development.
    => address: localhost
    => port: 8000
    => log: normal
    => workers: 8
    => secret key: generated
    => limits: forms = 32KiB
    => keep-alive: 5s
    => tls: disabled``
```

Ее можно менять.
Как ее нужно  изменить, чтобы получить доступ к сайту с другого компьютера подключенного к той же сети?
я нашел только такой вариант изменения конфигурации для решения моей проблемы:

```
[global]
address = "0.0.0.0"

[development]
address = "0.0.0.0"
```

но что делать дальше, после установки данной конфигурации чтобы зайти на сайт с другого компьютера и по какому адресу это делать?

Comment: По адресу машины на которой работает сервер. Изучайте сети, это не вопрос к Rust-у, прям совсем.

Comment: У сервера будет свой IP адрес в локальной сети (обычно начинается с 192.168) по нему и нужно заходить. Т. е. если локальный IP сервера -- 192.168.0.1, то в адресной строке хоста пишите 192.168.0.1:8000.